# jackrabbit start repository slow

Tags: jackrabbit

In my current Tomcat Project, I integrated JackRabbit. Its functionality works well. However, the start of the repository is very slow. It took around 5 seconds. I think this is not bearable. Anyone has some ideas about how to integrate the Jackrabbit to the web project?

Currently, I have my own Session factory in the web project. Code is as following:

```
 public class TMPSessionFactory {
   public static Session getSession() throws RepositoryException, NamingException {
    String configFile = "C:\\workspaces\\repository.xml";
    String repHomeDir = "C:\\JackRabbitDemo\\repository";
    Hashtable<String, Object> hashTable = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    hashTable.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, DummyInitialContextFactory.class.getName());
    hashTable.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "127.0.0.1");
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(hashTable);
    RegistryHelper.registerRepository(ctx, "repo", configFile, repHomeDir, true);
    Repository r = (Repository) ctx.lookup("repo");

    SimpleCredentials cred = new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
    Session session = r.login(cred, null);

    return session;}}
```

Each time if I need a jackrabbit session, I will call this static function.

I don't know whether my way is appropriate or not since it works but not well enough (each time, the start of the repository is slow).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you create a new repository and bind it to JNDI before doing a look up each time you want to access your repository ?
All this code:

```
String configFile = "C:\\workspaces\\repository.xml";
String repHomeDir = "C:\\JackRabbitDemo\\repository";
Hashtable<String, Object> hashTable = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
hashTable.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, DummyInitialContextFactory.class.getName());
hashTable.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "127.0.0.1");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(hashTable);
RegistryHelper.registerRepository(ctx, "repo", configFile, repHomeDir, true);
```

should be only called once.
Maybe you should declared your jackrabbit repository as a Tomcat resource as it is documented here : https://jackrabbit.apache.org/shared-j2ee-resource-howto.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is I am using Tomcat 7 now. I tried similar configuration as the document said before but it seems it doesn't work. Do you have some idea about this?